# Find a real number such that the piecewise function is continuous

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

I am reasoning about this problem. The text asks to find a real number $a$ such that the piecewise function $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 3x+2 \;\;\;\; x < 2 \\ x^2+a \;\;\;\;  x\geq 2 \end{cases}$$ is continuous. It gives the hint to compute the left hand and right hand limits.

May I solve this exercise simply by applying a limit property, namely: in order for the total function to be continuous the limit of the sum of the functions has to equal the limits of the individual functions? Thus, $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 2 }  3x +2 = \lim_{  x \rightarrow 2}   x^2 + a = f(2) = 8$$ Thus, $a = 4$ ?

Comment: That's it, except you should precise left and right limit :
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-} 3x+2 = \lim_{x \rightarrow 2^+} x^2 + a$

Comment: you are right, but let me write  this formally $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-} f(x)= \lim_{x \rightarrow 2^+} f(x)  $$ and so  $$ 8=4+a$$ so that  $a=4$.

Comment: Could one of you two post an answer to upvote/accept. please, so that this question is removed from the unanswered list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, but let me write it formmaly. To ensure the continuity of $f$, you should have  $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-} f(x)= \lim_{x \rightarrow 2^+} f(x)$$ i.e. $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-} 3x+2= \lim_{x \rightarrow 2^+} x^2+a$$ and so  $$ 8=4+a$$ Thus  $a=4$.